# Create Custom Angular 2 Service to Package in NPM

Tags: angular, npm

I am looking to create a custom service in Angular 2 that I can bundle and minify and then have hosted privately on NPM. Then when I create applications, I can run a simple *npm install customService* and have that service available in my application. I can't find any guides online, was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction. In the future I would also like to do this with components as well. My goal is to abstract some of the features out and then allow myself to create apps in the future that can use these without worrying about details.

Comment: Why dont you start by checking out some of the packages already out there? There's a ton on github and they all provide some kind of direction on how to approach it.

Comment: Any chance you could point me towards one? When creating a Angular 2 service, will I need to create an app.component, index.html, etc.? I literally just want 1 service and be able to run a production build on it which will give me a minified version, that I can then host privately with NPM.

Comment: @user2516663 [here is a simple one](https://github.com/seiyria/ionic2-pagination) - disclaimer: I made this

Comment: @Seiyria Thanks. Are all those files created by you, or does running any of the npm scripts generate them?

Comment: @user2516663 most of it is created by `tsc`, some of it is just standard stuff I carry from project to project (gitignore, npmignore, etc). the only thing I wrote was `src/pagination.component.ts`.

Comment: @Seiyria so by writing the src/pagination.component.ts file, running npm generated the .d.ts files, the index.ts file, etc?

Comment: @user2516663 Pretty much. There's probably some unneeded files in there because I was struggling to get it to work with typescript, but it works so I'm not complaining.